# @Transient Custom query in Spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have two entities post, comment and I want to create a native query using spring data JPA

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * , (select count(*) from comments commentObj 
                where commentObj.post = postObj.id) as total_comments 
                FROM posts postObj 
                where postObj.status ='1' 
                order by total_comments desc",nativeQuery = true)
List<Post> fetchPosts();
```

```
@Entity(name = "posts")
@Data
public class Post{
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String post;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "user")
    private AppUser user;
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient
    private  long total_comments;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "comment")
   @JsonIgnore
   private List<Comment> commentList;
}


@Entity(name = "comments")
@Data
public class Comment{
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String comment;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "user")
    private AppUser user;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "post")
    private Post post;
   
}
```

It's working fine when I run this query and total_comments persist successfully. But occurs an error when I create a new object of type post in the database saying.

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'posts_.total_comments' in 'field list'

NOTE: I used @Transient from `javax.persistence.Transient` and I found out that it is not working at persisting total_comments column.

Comment: You should add source for `AppUser` too, and hopefully someone will help you. E.g.: `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "comment")` should be `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "post")`. And fields annotated with @Transient are not persisted.